# Bot Management: Error occurs when fetching bot

Tags: c#, azure-functions, bots, toolkit

Why do I keep seeing this error message in the Bot Management page of https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/bots?
The bots I previously created were gone. I'd like to delete them completely.

[Bot Management Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFknU.png)

Advanced thanks to you who can answer this ;)

I just browsed the page trying to delete the bots I previously played around with, but they were gone and this error message appears. I also could not do "Prepare Teams App Dependencies" in the Teams ToolKit in Visual Studio maybe because of this.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bot framework issue and just has been resolved, please try again to see if your error is still appearing or not.